# JNA call RegisterDeviceNotification fails with error 1066

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I am attempting to register for notifications on USB device arrival and device remove complete events from a java swing application.

I have successfully called

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd, MyUser32.GWLP_WNDPROC, listener);
```

to register a listener and I am getting notifications of type `WM_DEVICECHANGE`.  So far so good.

Now I want to call RegisterDeviceNotification to ensure that I am notified of device arrival and remove complete events.  Here is what I have tried:

```
HWND hWnd = new HWND();
hWnd.setPointer(Native.getWindowPointer(frame));
DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE filter = new DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE();
filter.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE;       
filter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
filter.dbcc_name = new char[1];
filter.dbcc_reserved = new DWORD(0);
filter.dbcc_size = new DWORD(filter.size());
filter.dbcc_size = new DWORD(filter.size());

long retVal = MyUser32.MYINSTANCE.RegisterDeviceNotification(new HANDLE(hWnd.getPointer()), filter.getPointer(), DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);

if (retVal != 0) {
    System.out.println("Error registering for usb: " + Native.getLastError());
}
```

My JNA declarations are:

```
public long RegisterDeviceNotification(HANDLE hRecipient, Pointer NotificationFilter, DWORD Flags);

public static class DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE extends Structure {
      public DWORD dbcc_size;
      public DWORD dbcc_devicetype;
      public DWORD dbcc_reserved;
      public GUID  dbcc_classguid;
      public char[] dbcc_name;
}

public static final GUID GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE = new GUID(new byte[] {
        (byte)0xA5, (byte)0xDC, (byte)0xBF, 0x10, 0x65, 0x30, 0x11, (byte)0xD2, (byte)0x90, 0x1F, 0x00, (byte)0xC0, 0x4F, (byte)0xB9, 0x51, (byte)0xED          
});
```

I am always receiving an error 1066.  Any help would be appreciated.  If more information is required let me know and I can include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring RegisterDeviceNotification to return long was causing the problem.  According to the JNA FAQ, [JNA FAQ](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#how-do-i-map-a-native-long-type)

> Actually, no one ever asks this question, but they really need the
>   answer. Do not use Java long!
>
> On Windows, you can use a Java int, since the native long type is
>   always 32 bits. On any other platform, the type may be 32 or 64 bits,
>   so you should use the NativeLong type to ensure the proper size is
>   used.