# JNA call to RegisterDeviceNotification returning 1066 error

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I have already gone through the following post and changed the return type to nativelong but still it is failing with 1066 error and my code exactly looks same as in the following link
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540011/jna-call-registerdevicenotification-fails-with-error-1066)

please help...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it only change that i have made is

"Declare the second argument of RegisterDeviceNotification() to be of type DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE and pass the arg directly (instead of Structure.getPointer())" and it worked.
Some more suggestions to keep in mind :

1. Make sure you declare your structure field order (3.5.0 and later requires this; earlier depend on the JVM doing the expected thing if you don't specify it).
2. dbcc_name might be char[] or byte[] depending on whether you're using ASCII/UNICODE mapping.

Hope this helps...
Thank you.